# webview cannot load index.html

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

Hello everyone i have an issue , i place all the file like html, css, js in assets folder but it did not show me on a webview. 
Check the images.
[Index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u9YY.jpg)

And this this the assets folder [Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvNRu.jpg)

Here is the code in the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    WebSettings webSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        assert webView != null;
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///assets/index.html","text/html","utf-8",null,null);

        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        ////////////////////////////////

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching online it looks like you need to use `android_asset` instead of `assets` in the path url. Also, it looks like your index.html is under another folder called themes so the correct url would be `"file:///android_asset/themes/index.html"`. If I was just looking at that image incorrectly then the correct url is `"file:///android_asset/index.html"`. Also, use `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");` instead because you are not using the other method correctly. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: no in the assets folder there are two sub-folder 10)images  2)theme

Comment: sorry I was being unclear I edited my answer @DanishButt

Comment: @DanishButt can you just try `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")`. It may be that the method you are using is incorrect for this case.

Comment: @DanishButt can you accept my answer so people can see that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

[`loadDataWithBaseUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has 5 params: `baseUrl`, `data`, `mimeType`, `encoding`, and `historyUrl`. Your app tries to load as data "text/html" with `mimeType == utf8`. All params are messed up.

And this method works in another way. WebView doesn't load `baseUrl`, WebView loads some html from second param `data`.